# How to speedup my multithreading program?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have Pthread wrapper class:

```
class MyPthreadWrapper : public Thread{
public:
    MyPthreadWrapper(bool* basicSieve, bool* curSieve,     unsigned int startCell, unsigned int endCell, unsigned int rootFromMaxV);        

    ~MyPthreadWrapper();

    void run();

    long long runTime;
private:    
    bool* curSieve;   
    bool* basicSieve;
    unsigned int startCell,endCell,rootFromMaxV;        
};
```

And this is realization run-method, which will run in different threads:

```
void MyPthreadWrapper::run(){
    if (startCell<=endCell){
        long long startTime=getCurrentTimeInMS();        
        for (int i=2; i<=rootFromMaxV; i++){
            if (basicSieve[i]==false){
                unsigned int j=i*i;
                if (j<=endCell){
                    unsigned int startJ2=((startCell+i-1)/i)*i;                                   
                    if (startJ2>j){
                        j=startJ2;
                    }                    
                    for (; j<=endCell; j+=i){
                        curSieve[j-startCell]=1;                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }        
        runTime=getCurrentTimeInMS()-startTime;
    }
}
```

BasicSieve array is common for all threads, its size is ~50MB. CurSieve array will be different for each thread, its size is ~400MB. BasicSieve array contain prime numbers in range [2..45000] (if (basicSieve[i]==false), then i is prime). Inner loop will work for each prime i-iterator (difference between endCell and startCell is ~400000000, therefore for i==2 inner loop will run ~200000000 iterations, and so on. If I run my program on my home computer, runtime is **23.6s** for **single** thread, **18.5s** for **four** threads and **19.2s** for **8** threads (processor i7-4770, 8GB RAM). But if I run program on server computer (Xeon E5-2690, 64GB RAM) it work ***40.4s*** for ***single*** thread, ***12.7s*** for ***four*** threads and ***10.8s*** for ***8*** threads. How to explain it? I found problem in the line of code

```
curSieve[j-startCell]=1;
```

If we remove from this line access to array curSieve, speedup of program will proportional to the number of threads. How I can fix it, to speedup appear on any computer?

Comment: What are the typical `j` and `endCell` are at the start of the inner loop? IOW, how much data is being processed by this inner loop?

Comment: Well, you should probably consider the fact that the Xeon processor has 8 physical cores, the i7 has 4 cores and can run two threads simultaneously on each core when conditions are perfect (rarely happens). Basically the HyperThreading logical core doesn't work to its fullest unless the physical core is stalled waiting for something like a memory fetch. It will never come anywhere near the performance level of 8 physical cores. Consider cutting the thread count back to something more realistic like 4 or 6 for the i7 CPU.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: I've also thought about physical vs. HT cores but he still has four real cores and I would expect at least 2x improvement with that given that there is no locking involved. So I'd bet on cache pressure, because that's 20 MB vs 8 MB and if you divide that between 4 or 8 threads, there is not that much left. I'd probably try using bitsets for this task and see whether it helps (coupled with more efficient value setting, maybe).